# Why do I get 5 bytes worth of 0x00 hex values in both outputs?

Tags: script, raw-transaction, output, createrawtransaction

From the hex generated by the `createrawtransaction` command, I understand that the following is the output value:

> 60e316**0000000000**1976a914ab68025513c3dbd2f7b92a94e0581f5d50f654e788acd0ef80**0000000000**1976a9147f9b1a7fb68d60c536c2fd8aeaa53a8f3cc025a888ac

Output one - Receiver address details:

> 60e316**0000000000**1976a914ab68025513c3dbd2f7b92a94e0581f5d50f654e788ac

Output two - Change address details:

> d0ef80**0000000000**1976a9147f9b1a7fb68d60c536c2fd8aeaa53a8f3cc025a888ac

My question is regarding the highlighted 0 values, as in the 0x00 hex values.  I understand these are empty arrays, but why 5 bytes worth?  Is this some sort of padding for the maximum allowed satoshi's which can be sent?  Or are these for some other purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` of an output in a transaction is a `8-byte` field encoded in `little-endian`. The value is always represented with `8 bytes` no matter how small it is. Here you have the full transaction structure with sizes:

[image]